# Is this a valid sentence?

Tags: sentence-meaning, grammaticality

I have an argument about this with two friends. We are not native English speakers. We read a sentence and are not certain if it is a valid sentence. We can all understand it but we do not agree if it is valid or not. Translators will do just fine in translating it. Spell/grammar checkers did not find errors. The sentence in question:

> Tickets must be submitted no longer than 3 hours of the event ending.

Is there anything missing here? Can you leave it like it is?

Comment: Native English speakers. Such a simple rule.

Comment: It is all wrong:  "Tickets will be collected no later than three house after the event ends." Yep, I am a translator.... tickets are not submitted at events. They might presumably be handed in. **The issues here are not grammatical; they are semantic** and idiomatic.

Comment: One grammar mistake in fact: three hours after the event ends.//not three hours of the event ending.

Comment: Thanks. I think specifically the last part of the sentence was the issue for us. Not sure what your first comment suggests though.

Comment: To be a sentence, it must be understandable.

Comment: _Within_ no longer than three hours?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue 1:

> no longer than 3 hours of the event ending.

This isn't grammatically correct, and should be modified.  Here is one option:

> no later than 3 hours after the event ends.

Issue 2:

> Tickets must be submitted

should most likely be

> Tickets will be collected

This change isn't about grammar, but about choosing idiomatic words to go with "events" and "tickets".

Issue 3:

Finally, even with these changes the whole sentence still doesn't make sense. You don't go to an event and submit (or collect) a ticket - *three hours after the event has ended.*  It's grammatical but nonsensical like "I turned off the television, to watch the program."

Unless you don't mean "ticket", but perhaps "voucher for a free meal", or something else.

---

By the way, it is possible to use "of" (which appeared in your original sentence) when discussing a time period. However, it doesn't go with "no longer".

> If you get to the hospital **within** 3 hours **of** the first symptoms of an ischemic stroke, you may get a type of medicine called a thrombolytic.

Comment: Nice breakdown. Exactly what I was looking for!